# are there two predicate verbs in the sentence?

Tags: predicate

Designers, or visual design communicators ,as they  are referred to in the profession,
 got on board the web medium rather late and ,in their initial efforts,
created many "online brochures".

`as they are referred to in the profession`is a modifier, we can omit it and do not affect the whole sentence

Designers, or visual design communicators , got on board the web medium rather late and ,in their initial efforts,
created many "online brochures".

1.what is the meaning of  `got on board` in `got on board the web medium rather late`?
2.`created many "online brochures` and `ot on board the web medium rather late` are all predicate verbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Get on board* means to *enter a vehicle* such as a ship (the original sense), a train or a bus. Here it is used figuratively to mean that these designers started working on the internet, thought of as a vehicle carrying many people into new territory.
2. Yes, this sentence has two VPs with the same subject NP. The two VPs are fairly long, but the structure is really no different from *John went to McDonalds and ate lunch.*.